# Sending JSON to Flask, request.args vs request.form

Tags: python, json, rest, flask, post

My understanding is that `request.args` in Flask contains the URL encoded parameters from a `GET` request while `request.form` contains `POST` data. What I'm having a hard time grasping is why when sending a `POST` request, trying to access the data with `request.form` returns a `400` error but when I try to access it with `request.args` it seems to work fine.

I have tried sending the request with both `Postman` and `curl` and the results are identical.

```
curl -X POST -d {"name":"Joe"} http://127.0.0.1:8080/testpoint --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

Code:

```
@app.route('/testpoint', methods = ['POST'])
def testpoint():
    name = request.args.get('name', '')
    return jsonify(name = name)
```

Answer (score 66):

You are POST-ing JSON, neither `request.args` nor `request.form` will work.

`request.form` works only if you POST data *with the right content types*; *form data* is either POSTed with the [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data) encodings.

When you use `application/json`, you are no longer POSTing form data. Use [`request.get_json()`](https://flask.readthedocs.org/api/#flask.Request.get_json) to access JSON POST data instead:

```
@app.route('/testpoint', methods = ['POST'])
def testpoint():
    name = request.get_json().get('name', '')
    return jsonify(name = name)
```

As you state, `request.args` only ever contains values included in the request query string, the optional part of a URL after the `?` question mark. Since it’s part of the URL, it is independent from the POST request body.

Answer (score 3):

Your json data in curl is wrong, so Flask does not parse data to form.

Send data like this: `'{"name":"Joe"}'`

```
curl -X POST -d '{"name":"Joe"}' http://example.com:8080/testpoint --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

Comment: The problem is that the OP is posting JSON in the first place, then using methods meant for *form data* to access the information.

Answer (score 1):

just change args for form and it will work

```
@app.route('/testpoint', methods = ['POST'])
def testpoint():
    name = request.form.get('name', '')`enter code here`
    return jsonify(name = name)
```